# Toggle a boolean column with sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, toggle

I want to toggle a particular column with type `boolean` in postgres using sequelize. I do not want to use the `sequelize.query()` option, yet, I want it done in one call. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you use sequelize models? nameModel.update({ isExample: true }, { where : {} });

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Sequelize.literal](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-literal)

```
model.update({ name: Sequelize.literal('NOT name') }, { where: { id } });
```